# TimerTask chamando método duas vezes

Tags: java, thread, javafx, timer

Tenho um `TimerTask` que chama um método de 1 em 1 minuto, porém o método é chamado duas vezes. Esse método verifica alguns fatores e envia um email, como o método é chamado duas vezes o email é enviado duas vezes. Alguém sabe aonde possa estar o problema?

```
private void tarefa() {
        new Timer().schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        alertaGeral();
                        System.out.println("Alertando..");
                    }

                }, 0, 1000 * 60 * 1);
    }
```

Método que é chamado no `TimerTask`:

```
private void alertaGeral() {
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            String hora = df.format(new Date());

            SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date hour = formatador.parse(hora);
            Time time = new Time(hour.getTime());

            Calendar alertDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            alertDate.setTime(time);
            alertDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

            Date d = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String data = dateFormat.format(d);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date dataf = formatter.parse(data);

            List<Compromisso> lista = atualizarDataInicial(s);

            for (Compromisso c : lista) {
                Time time1 = new Time(c.getHoraInicial().getTime());
                java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(c.getDataInicio().getTime());
                Calendar alertHour = Calendar.getInstance();
                alertHour.setTime(time1);
                alertHour.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);

                if (alertHour.compareTo(alertDate) == 0 && utilDate.compareTo(dataf) == 0) {
                    EnviaEmail e = new EnviaEmail();
                    e.enviaEmail(c.getNomeBeneficiario(), c.getDataInicio(), c.getHoraInicial(), c.getCompromisso());
                }
                System.out.println("HORA INICIAL CORRETA: " + c.getHoraInicial());
                System.out.println("HORA INICIAL ADIANTADA: " + alertHour.getTime());
                System.out.println("HORA SISTEMA " + alertDate.getTime());

            }
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A forma de agendar a execução das tarefas parece ok. A forma de mandar o email também (desde que `lista` contenha um elemento, senão irá mandar email mais de uma vez mesmo, por causa do `for`). Falta saber se o método `tarefa()` está sendo chamado mais de uma vez. Verifique colocando um breakpoint na primeira linha dele (`new Timer().schedule`) e debugando, ou então postando a classe que chama esse método para a gente olhar.

Comment: Eu chamo o método `tarefa()` no construtor. E só contem 1 elemento na lista depois que ela entra no `IF`. Ou seja, o email enviado são idênticos.

Comment: Provavelmente seu problema é o seguinte: às 10:30:00 execute "x". Ele por sua executa as 10:30:00 - mas foi tão rápido que ainda é 10:30:00 (não se passou 1 segundo ainda) e ele chama de novo o método. Experimente parar sua task após a tarefa "x". Coloque um sleep de 1 segundo na task e verifique se ele executa duas vezes.

Comment: @Dener Isso seria um defeito na implementação de `Timer`. A versão do método `schedule()` que está sendo usada é baseada em milissegundos e não em segundos ou uma data fixa.

Comment: @Techies Qual é a classe desse construtor? E quem chama esse construtor? Precisamos do contexto todo para investigar se ele está sendo chamado mais de uma vez. Se você quer ter certeza que não, debugue como sugeri.

Comment: Esse é o Contrutor: `public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        init();
        tarefa();
        alertaInicial();

    }`

Comment: Realmente é estranho. Não vi nada problemático em seu código. Apesar disso, pode ser que o método `alertaGeral()` lance alguma exceção fazendo com que o Timer pare de funcionar.

Comment: Se eu uso o componente Alert do javaFX no método alertaGeral da erro também kk

Comment: Mas você foi atrás de log de erro para tentar descobrir qual é o problema?

Comment: Sim, o erro do Alert eu contornei fazendo o envio de emails. O erro era esse: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-0`

Comment: Achou a solução para esse problema?

Comment: Ainda não resolvi @DanielGomes, era um projeto "teste"